# rails 7 touchpunch not draggable on mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling to get a jquery slider to be draggable in the mobile app.

I have added touchpunch to my Gemfile but I get the following error when loading the page:

`couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/mouse' with type 'application/javascript'`

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.5.1'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '6.0.1'
gem 'touchpunch-rails', '1.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks', '5.2.1'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '2.1.0'
etc.
```

js file:

```
//= require jquery
// require jquery-ui/widgets/slider
//= require jquery.ui.touch-punch
```

I recently upgraded to Rails 7 so I dont know if that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got this working as follows. I removed the touchpunch gem from my Gemfile. I required this file by: //= require ./touch_slider/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js. I downloaded this .js file from: https://www.cdnpkg.com/jqueryui-touch-punch/file/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js/. It worked: I can now slide the sliders on a mobile device. (Note: just using the touchpunch gem did not work for me)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and solved inserting directly what I needed in the gem touch-punch, which was mouse and widget:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery.ui.widget.min.js"></script>`

got the script info from https://www.cdnpkg.com/jqueryui/file/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js/

hope it helps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks Steven.    I tried including these 2 files but the result is the same for me - sliding only works on desktop and not mobile.   A few questions:   (1) Do you mean I need to remove touchpunch gem from my Gemfile? (2) Should I also still require 'jquery-ui/slider' in my javascript, before requiring these 2 files?  Thanks.